# How to integrate Push sharp for Android GCM (Pushnotification)?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I am referring this link to implement push sharp in android,
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp#monotouch-and-mono-for-android-client-application-integration

But given code is in .cs,
So please suggest how to use this library in android,share any kind of documentation regarding this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the link you supplied suggests that this library works with MonoTouch and Mono for Android. I'm not familiar with those, but you don't have to use them for your client side (even if you use PushSharp in your server).
You can simply use the code samples in the [GCM developer guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) (which are all in Java).